# Automating Process Of SQL Query Files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In a folder I have 120 files, each with 10,000 sql insert statements.  Is there any way in sql server management studio, I can tell it to open each file one at a time and run the insert statements inside them?

I assume no, but I have to ask.  Otherwise I'll be manually opening them and manually running them, and with 120 files it'll be nothing short of awful.

Thanks

Comment: Not that it wouldn't be equally dreadful, but you could run them in a BAT file.  I don't know DOS well enough to know if you could get the BAT file to loop through the folder's contents and run them one by one, as opposed to listing them all out in the BAT file itself, but it's probably possible.  Surely, you could do it in a Windows Scripting file as well.

Comment: Could you maybe combine all 120 (i know, itll be a PITA, but youll only have to do it once) into 1 file, then just execute them as a SQL Agent job?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running them in a batch file or powershell script.  Here are some examples:

[Batch file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e00c796-5854-4a2c-91d3-7b325420fd14/how-to-create-batch-file-to-execute-sql-scripts?forum=sqlgetstarted)

[Powershell](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b811c1b7-1fda-4027-ab97-9ecb1fabff36/how-to-execute-sql-script-using-windows-powershellusing-invokesqlcmd-or-any-if?forum=sqlsecurity)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  What I ended up doing was combining the sql files into one (by just regenerating them as 1 file instead of 120).  I generated it without the insert text and just the data.  Then I used bcp and just did an import.